# Understanding this regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression I got from Internet to match URL links in `<a>` tags. It appears as below:

```
variable = re.compile('<a\s(?:.*?\s)*?href=[\'"](.*?)[\'"].*?>')
```

Would anyone please explain me how exactly is this patten going to match the contents of an `<a>` tag?

I have basic understanding of regular expression in Unix but this looks too complicated for me and appreciate anybody explaining this to me.

Comment: Did you check the [Python regular expression](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) documentation? Was there anything in it specifically you didn't understand?

Comment: Write up a number of href-tags and try removing specific parts of the regex to see how it changes what it matches and what doesn't match.

Comment: and the usual must: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 3):

`'<a\s(?:.*?\s)*?href=[\'"](.*?)[\'"].*?>'`

lets break it down.

- `<a` is just that, the start of a tag.
- `\s` means a whitespace.
- `(?:.*?\s)*?` means a non-capturing group, repeated as many times as it can, or not at all,
  the contents of this group are `.*?`: anything, and then a whitespace.
- `href=` is just that, part of the tag.
- `[\'"]` means either `'` or `"`
- `(.*?)` is your capturing group, which captures anything.
- `[\'"]` means either `'` or `"`
- `.*?` anything, or nothing
- `>` just that, the end of the tag.

what does this mean in english?

`<a ANYTHING href=URL>`

ANYTHING is ignored, and URL is captured.

small details:

- the URL is surrounded with quotation characters, either `'` or `"` (hence the inclusion in the regex).
- ANYTHING are possible attributes that might exist on the link.
- if you understand basic HTML, then you know that any link is in tags `<a> ... </a>` or `<a ... >`
- the `href=` is the attribute we want - which is the link address.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning the `?` being used to make qualifiers non-greedy. (In this case, it prevents two or more tags being read as one)

Comment: @DanielB yes, this code is dynamic enough that if you DID want to capture the attributes you could just remove the `?:` from the non-capturing group to make it capturing.

Comment: For example, here's the same pattern with one `?` removed http://regex.utahraptor.info/r/2/

Comment: @DanielB dude, what is that site - how does it work?

Comment: I don't want to spam here, but it's a javascript-client with a python-server. There's a contact email on the site if you want more details.

Answer (score 0):

Well the @Inbar rose has already answered your question in detail,
but there may be some links which will have a problem when you use the regular expression for getting the links.. Incase you can get them by using the normal split functions, taking into consideration the general html syntax -

```
a='<a href="http://www.google.com">'r
print a.split('href=')[1].split('"')[1]

>> http://www.google.com
```

Comment: you wrote in your split `'href='` but it is not in your example. which is somewhat confusing.

Comment: @InbarRose - I'm sorry that was a mistake.. I've edited it again.